# What do these things have in common?

Tags: riddle, word

There are three sets of these puzzles you are required to answer!

Set 1:

> Buck
>   Baby
>   Wisdom

Set 2:

> Scavenger
>   Fox
>   Treasure

Set 3:

> Year
>   Address
>   Scrap

Remember; you need to get all three!

Comment: You say, “There are three sets of these puzzles you are required to answer!”  I would quibble with that: there are three *puzzles*, not three ***sets* of puzzles** (there are, arguably, three sets of clues).  But I'm making the point that, lacking a link, these are ***three separate*** puzzles, and I don't see any good reason to post them together in one question. (Then again, if you posted them as three separate questions, they would probably get downvoted for being to easy.  I solved all three in about a minute, once I got around to reading this question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set 1

> buck-tooth, baby-tooth, wisdom-tooth

Set 2

> scavenger-hunt, fox-hunt, treasure-hunt

Set 3

> year-book, address-book, scrap-book

Comment: Should I be finding a meta-link?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean should I be looking for a similar way to link the three solutions?

Comment: no, you got it.

Comment: I wish the original puzzle took longer to figure out, but I will occupy myself with finding a satisfying way to link "tooth hunt book" in the mean time...

Answer (score 1):

Set 1:

> TOOTH

Set 2:

> HUNT

Set 3:

> BOOK

We can combine these to form

> this alphametic:
> \begin{align}\text{TOOTH}\\-\quad\text{HUNT}\\\hline\text{BOOK}\end{align}
> i.e.,
> TOOTH − HUNT = BOOK
> (because we obviously can’t have TOOTH + HUNT = BOOK)

Or, equivalently,

> BOOK + HUNT = TOOTH
>
> BOOK < 9999 and HUNT < 9999, so TOOTH < 19998. 
> Therefore, T ≤ 1. 
> If we make the standard assumption that numbers don’t have leading zeroes,
> then T = 1. 
> Similarly, B ≠ 0 and H ≠ 0. 
> Making the standard assumption of a unique mapping, H ≠ 1,
> and, if H = 2, then K = 1 (from the rightmost column<sup>0</sup>:
> K + T = H (with possible carry);
> i.e., K + 1 = H or K = H − 1), which also violates uniqueness. 
> So H ≥ 3.
> ______
> <sup>0</sup> I’ll refer to the rightmost column (the units column) as column 0
> because it represents the 10<sup>0</sup> values. 
> Moving to the left, the columns are 1, 2, 3, and 4.

> So, anyway, column 0 cannot carry (because H cannot be 0,
> and K + 1 cannot be larger than 10). 
> In column 1 we have O + N = T = 1 (with possible carry). 
> Neither O nor N can be 1, and so neither of them can be zero
> (i.e., O ≥ 2 and N ≥ 2),
> so this sum must carry (i.e., O + N = 11, so N = 11 − O). 
> So, in column 2, 1 (carry) + O + U = O (with carry),
> so U = 9 and column 2 carries. 
> And, since N ≠ 9 (because U = 9), N ≤ 8 and O ≥ 3.

> Looking at column 3, 1 (carry) + B + H = 10 + O;
> i.e., B + H = 9 + O (or B = 9 + O − H). 
> B ≠ 9 (because U = 9), so B < 9, so H > O. 
> And O cannot be H − 1 (because that’s K), so O < H − 1; i.e., O < K. 
> Since O ≥ 3, we have K ≥ 4 and H ≥ 5.

I had to go to brute force here.

> Suppose H = 5 and K = 4. 
> Since O < K, O must be 3 and N = 8. 
> B = 9 + O − H = 7, giving us a solution:
> \begin{align}13315\\-\quad5981\\\hline7334\end{align}

> Suppose H = 6 and K = 5. 
> We can have O = 3 and N = 8, or O = 4 and N = 7. 
> O = 3 gives us B = 9 + 3 − 6 = 6, which equals H and so is a contradiction. 
> O = 4 gives us B = 9 + 4 − 6 = 7, which equals N and so is a contradiction.

> Suppose H = 7 and K = 6. 
> We can have (O,N) = (3,8), (4,7) or (5,6) —
> but the second and third choices give us N equal to either H or K. 
> (3,8) gives us B = 9 + 3 − 7 = 5, which gives us the solution
> \begin{align}13317\\-\quad7981\\\hline5336\end{align}

> Suppose H = 8 and K = 7. 
> We can have (O,N) = (3,8), (4,7), (5,6) or (6,5) —
> but the first and second choices give us N equal to either H or K. 
> (5,6) gives us B = 9 + 5 − 8 = 6, which equals N and so is a contradiction. 
> O = 6 gives us B = 7, which equals K and so is a contradiction.

> (H cannot be 9 because U = 9.)

P.S. There is a trivial alternative to the first puzzle:

> TEETH. 
> It turns out that TEETH - HUNT = BOOK has eight solutions.
>
> OK, yeah; I suppose I could say HUNTS or BOOKS, too;
> I didn’t even look at those.